# Add "Answered by Me And Accepted by the Questioner" function

Tags: feature-request, search, accepted-answer

After using the site for a period of time and having looked at the documentation, I still didn't find anything about how to find out "Answered by me and accepted by the Questioner" threads for a period of time..

It seems that I can only see "Answered" posts (maybe answered by others or answered by me but not marked as an answer). So if it is possible to:

1. Add a DateTime picker or something like this for users to look up from what time to what time a user is active in what kinds of forums.
2. In a specific site, how many answers are accepted by the questioner for the user (Answered by me, must be accepted by the questioner).
3. If possible, A list of choices can be offered to the user "Answered By me in a week, in a day or in a month, in a year etc.) for users to look up their successfully-accepted answers by others quickly.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum

Comment: So are you looking for something like http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aanswer+isaccepted%3A1?  That shows what you've answered which has been accepted. Just a note also that [voting on Meta works differently](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta), if you didn't know.

Comment: @psubsee2003: Why not a forum? if not a forum? what's that?

Comment: A Q&A. Question and Answer. Those are fundamentally different.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy from what I understand, he's looking for questions he answered, but the OP accepted a different answer. He says "Answered by me **but** accepted by the Questioner" - emphasis is mine.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: oh, that's something that can be done using the Data Explorer then.

Comment: @Sha I'm not sure about that, I think the Qantas's interpreation is correct

Comment: @Sha I assumed that was a mistake based on the original title and edited out the "but".

Comment: @Duncan guess only the OP here can tell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try the following in your search query:

```
is:a user:me isaccepted:1
```

- `is:a` will match all answers
- `user:me` will restrict to your answers alone
- `isaccepted:1` will limit results to those answers which were answered by me, and have been accepted by the questioner.

---

If you want the results from a date set or other filters, you can take a look at the advanced search tips on [help-pages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

---

To specifically answer [your comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204020/add-answered-by-me-and-accepted-by-the-questioner-function/204021?noredirect=1#comment651087_204021):

```
is:a user:me isaccepted:1 created:2013-01-01..2013-11-01
```

Comment: Why you put a totally irrelevant quote in the beginning?

Comment: Hi hjpotter92: But how can I search for a period of time? such as from 2013.1.1 to 2013.11.1?

Comment: @DWHelper: http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: @DWHelper Check the *Dates* section in the link I provided at the end

Comment: Thanks hjpotter92: You've answered 90% of my question, in fact what I hope is that you can do searching in StackExchange in the search textbox. I tried to do that but failed.... Can I only do that in a specfic forum?

Comment: @DWHelper again, SE is not a forum

Comment: OK, it seems that StackExchange is only an entrance of all the other forums. So it would be nice if it can allow us to do searching and listing all the threads satisfying my needs;)

Comment: @DWHelper why do you keep using "forum" when multiple people have said we're not a forum.  Stack Exchanges strives very hard to be different than forums so the terminology is not accurate.

Comment: @DWHelper but to answer your question, the custom search is only available in the individual SE sites.  The global search from StackExchange.com is different and doesn't recognize the specific operators.  But the fact that you were looking to do a global search across all SE sites was missing from your question.

Comment: It would be nice if I can do a global searching....don't you think so?

Comment: @DWHelper you can do a global search, just not with the custom operators that are available in the individual sites.  And I haven't found a need to do that level of search so I don't know how much it is needed.  If you think that adding this to the global search is necessary, you can ask a new feature request to add it, but I really have no idea how well it will be received and if it would be supported (upvoted) or not.

Comment: Many thanks! I've added the tag "feature-requested";)